Lookup multiple columns in a single cell and return single value Excel
I have two Sheets ( Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 )
I would like to populate ORDER ID in Sheet 2 using the Asset tag from Sheet 2 and compare
the Asset tag in Sheet 1.
=VLOOKUP(""&B4&"",'Order Data'!Z:Z:'Order Data'!AA:AA,2,FALSE)
